# hq creates a new line and i need the columns to be 3 automatically

Tags: html, css

The columns are supposed to be just three, with multiple rows, but unfortunately it just displays everything in one line.

Also, I'm trying to have the quotes to have the same style, size and be in the same line as the text.

but it just starts a new line. Acually both quotes I want them to be inlines.

*Please ignore the fact that I'm using the styly="" instead of importing from css sheet. I's for a limited amout of time until I have the right code I will move the style to the CSS sheet.

```
<div class="expcont" style=" width: 60%; height: 600px;margin:0 auto;">
  <%-- CONTAINER --%>

    <div class="cont" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left;word-wrap: break-word; ">
      <%-- GRID OF BOXES BEGIN --%>
        <h1 style="display: inline;">❝</h1> TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1
        <h1>❞</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cont" style=" width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left;word-wrap: break-word; ">
      <h1>❝</h1> TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1
      <h1>❞</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cont" style=" width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left;word-wrap: break-word; ">
      <h1>❝</h1> TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1
      <h1>❞</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cont" style=" width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left;word-wrap: break-word; ">
      <h1>❝</h1> TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1
      <h1>❞</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `div` as child in parent `.cont` to handle wide of each of them.

also you can use `before`, `after` to `comma` in your css

> **Note: this style you created not work as responsive**

```css
.expcont {
  width: 60%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cont {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.cont div {
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.cont div:before {
  content: "❝";
  font-size: 2em;
}

.cont div:after {
  content: "❞";
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="expcont">
  <div class="cont">
    <div>
      TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont">
    <div>
      TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont">
    <div>
      TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont">
    <div>
      TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="expcont" style=" width: 60%; height: 600px;margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="cont" style="margin: 10px 15px; width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left;word-wrap: break-word; ">
        <h1 style="display: inline;">❝TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1❞</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cont" style="margin: 10px 15px; width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left;word-wrap: break-word; ">
        <h1 style="display: inline;">❝TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1❞</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cont" style="margin: 10px 15px; width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left;word-wrap: break-word; ">
        <h1 style="display: inline;">❝TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1❞</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cont" style="margin: 10px 15px; width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left;word-wrap: break-word; ">
        <h1 style="display: inline;">❝TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1TEST1❞</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```